# Cannot instantiate interface error when installing Magento 2.1.11 on production

Tags: php, magento2

I am facing the following errors while installing Magento 2.1.11 on production (CentOS, Apache):

```
        Notice: Undefined property: DOMDocument::$documentElement in /var/www/html/lexingtoncontainer/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Config/Mapper/Dom.php on line 58

        Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/lexingtoncontainer/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Config/Mapper/Dom.php on line 58

        Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/html/lexingtoncontainer/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Config/Mapper/Dom.php on line 58

        Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\Framework\Config\CacheInterface in /var/www/html/lexingtoncontainer/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:73 
Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/lexingtoncontainer/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(71): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\Framewo...')
     #1 /var/www/html/lexingtoncontainer/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(126): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\Framewo...')
     #2 /var/www/html/lexingtoncontainer/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(53): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, 'Magento\Framewo...', NULL, 'cache', 'Magento\Framewo...') 
    #3 /var/www/html/lexingtoncontainer/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(82): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Magento\ in /var/www/html/lexingtoncontainer/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php on line 73.
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. 
Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And further more, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please refer https://community.magento.com/t5/Technical-Issues/PHP-Fatal-error-Uncaught-Error-Class-DOMDocument-not-found-in/td-p/47718  Also check system requirements to install Magento2

Answer (score 0):

It's a permissions issue is this, please check all of your permissions (probably too late by now, but worth it if someone else is struggling)